# What is the runtime of my algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, trie, prefix-tree

I'm writing an algorithm that will first take a config file of various endpoints and their associated method like the following:

```
/guest guestEndpoint
/guest/lists listEndpoint
/guest/friends guestFriendsEndpoint
/guest/X/friends guetFriendsEndpoint
/guest/X/friends/X guestFriendsEndpoint
/X/guest guestEndpoint
/X/lists listEndpoint
/options optionsEndpoint
```

`X` here represents a wildcard, so any string would match with this.
The algorithm would take this as input and build a tree with each node representing one token between the `/`'s. Each leaf would be a valid endpoint.

Then when the user passes in something like `guest/abc/friends` it would traverse the tree starting from the root, then look for a `guest` node attached to the root, if it exists go to node `guest`, if `guest` here guest would have a `wildcard` node, so if `abc` did not match with any of `guest`'s nodes but there was a `wildcard` node present it would go to the `wildcard`. Then it would look from `wildcard` to see if it had a `friends` node, if so go there. Then if `friends`is a leaf node it would return the corresponding method.

Does this algorithm makes sense? I'm wondering what the runtime of the lookup would be. I'm thinking it would be O(n) where n is the number of tokens in the param that was passed in.

Here is an image of the graph I would build based on the input above. Each diamond represents an endpoint method.
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: so here wild card means a like a Joker we use in card's game?  Value of wild card can be matched with anything. right?

Comment: @user5250644 correct

Comment: Ok I am still confused with your tree. Can you post a image of tree for reference?

Comment: i agree with usersomething can you add more details to what it looks like and other related stuff

Comment: You mentioned 3 different algorithms in 3 different places in your question , which run time you want? is it look up? then please feel free to provide your tree details more.

Comment: @user5250644 Sure, I've added the graph image to the question. I am looking for the runtime of the lookup, so when I pass in something like `/guests/lists` how long it would take to verify this and find the endpoint method. I'm also just wondering if this is a good approach to solve this problem.

Comment: @monster Added an image of the graph I'm envisioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worst look up time will be O(E+N) where E is number if edges and N is number of nodes. Becuase We don't know how many nodes are there at each level. So by your algorithm you find first node in desired sequence by doing level search as you don't have any parameter to check for to going  through desired path.
(I know number of nodes are going to reduce each time I go down by one level but by how many is uncertain in this case)
It's Not even n-array.

Wild card won't help in reducing time complexity of worst case and will be uncertain to know the best case of a tree. Wild card checking takes constant time and it won't count in run time.

Now algorithm looks bit confusing what will you do when you have two options

1) you have natural matched node
2) you have wild card node.

On same level , where you will go?
Assume you we go in direction first you encountered. But what if It is not the actual path you get to know at last node so you backtrack it . To avoid that you will keep mark of number of available paths at each level by BFS and do the search.
So Worst Case time complexity would be O(E+N) provided you have handled all the cases.

Comment: Hmm, ok thank you. I really need the lookup time to be dependent on the # of tokens passed in the input string though. Any thoughts on what kind of algorithm I could use to achieve this? Maybe not using a tree at all. I thought this implementation would be close enough to a trie to have the same running time. I know tries are good for a prefix lookup type situation which is essentially what I have, except not prefixes but whole words.

Comment: @zulusam Look for something called as "n-gram" . It won't solve your problem completely but it will help you to solve your problem.